# Trying to plot a histogram with a list of tuples

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to produce a histogram with the data from a list of dictionaries, the data is in the format:

```
[{'price': 2.2, 'size': 100}, {'price': 2.4, 'size': 110}... etc...]
```

I would like to make 'price' the x axis and 'size' the y axis.

Comment: the common solution seems to be to break your structure into 2 lists like this: `x, y = zip(*my_data.items())`

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np
data =  [{'price': 2.2, 'size': 100}, {'price': 2.4, 'size': 110}]

x_val = [x['price'] for x in data]
y_val = [y['size'] for y in data]

plt.bar(x_val,y_val,align='center')
plt.axis([0, 4, 0, 120])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Would it be ok to ask how to modify this for a histogram?